# Can't re-install node_module in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

I had trouble with importing angular material. I read that I should delete `node_module` and run `npm install` to fix the bug. So i did it.
But now, the `node_module` folder isn't gereated again when i run `npm install`. And when i start my application i have the following mistake : [image]

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\ELISA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-U95ZIR\angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! xlsx-file-reader@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the xlsx-file-reader@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-12T11_27_43_777Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Can you try => Delete package-lock.json and  npm update

Or npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

Comment: didnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

i will advise you to reinstall angular-cli

```sh
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli
ng --version
```

Comment: please add your package.json, the command that causes the error and which node version you are using in order to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Delete package-lock.json File and then run

```
 npm install
```

Comment: check your internet its working fine? sometime its cause by internet problem.